# Windows 10 Print to PDF window not shown. Avlonia Window becomes unresponsive

Tags: .net-core, avaloniaui

I am printing a basic test document from my avalonia app. The problem is when I choose "Microsoft Print to PDF" from Windows 10 as my target printer, the app hangs and nothing happens.

I think the problem is, that the Avalonia Window is somehow preventing the *Save file dialog* associated with the print to pdf service from showing up.

A (almost) workaround is therefore to hide the window and then show it afterwards again like that:

```
private void PrintTestPage()
{
    window.Hide();

    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = SelectedPrinter;
    pd.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
    {
        e1.Graphics.DrawString("This is a test page.", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(0, 0, pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));

    };
    try
    {
        pd.Print();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error while printing: ", ex);
    }

    window.Show();
}
```

However when the user selects any other printer, the window will be hidden and shown for no reason. Apart from that I would like the save dialog to appear on top of my applications main window as in any other application, where I tested the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer.

I created a minimal example for reproduction on [Github](https://github.com/FrankenApps/PrintToPdfRepro).

Comment: Try printing from an STA thread.

Comment: You probably need to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.commondialog.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_CommonDialog_ShowDialog_System_Windows_Forms_IWin32Window_

Comment: Thank you for that hint, but unfortunately I was not really able to make any sense out of that. Would I need to use WinForms for that? If possible I would have liked to keep my code cross-platform. At the moment it works with all printers except the microsoft one...